# cmake to link external library with IMPORT_SONAME ro IMPORT_LOCATION

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project that links to a external library
The library was provided by a vendor which only contains a directory of .h headers and a shared object file "libabc.so".

in the CMakeLists of my project I have a obj(which I built it to bar.so) that uses the external lib.

when building the final exeuctable, I have tried mutilple ways to do it.

```
add_library(bar STATIC /some/source/file/bar.cpp)

add_library(abc_lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET abc_lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/to/external/lib/libabc.so)

add_executable(foo /some/file/to/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo bar abc_lib)
```

this builds ok and links ok, however when I do
`ldd foo`, the abc_lib does not appear in the form of

`abc.so => /path/to/external/lib/libabc.so`
instead it shows up in a standalone form
`/path/to/external/lib/libabc.so`, which indicates the library was not directly linked against according to some post I read recently.

But when I do `chrpath -d foo` or `patchelf --remove-rpath foo`the executable still contains the path and wont use the one I provided in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

so I tried the other way around

```
add_library(bar STATIC /some/source/file/bar.cpp)

add_library(abc_lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGE abd_lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_SONAME abc)
link_libraries(/path/to/external/lib)

add_executable(foo /some/file/to/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo bar abc_lib)
```

however this time, it complains abc_lib-NOTFOUND

To sum up my question, I would like to have a project built link against a local shared object and at the same time I should be able to clean up the rpath using `chrpath` or `patchelf` so that I can copy the executable to a server with similiar environment but possible different path to the external lib, I would like to overwrite the path using LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: May try to find the library first `find_library`, with the `PATHS ` options set, we will find the local library.

Answer (score 4):

The key you are looking for is [IMPORTED_NO_SONAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_NO_SONAME.html).
You can add an extra property to the shared imported library target:

```
set_property(TARGET abc_lib PROPERTY IMPORTED_NO_SONAME TRUE)
```

or better in one cmake command:

```
set_target_properties(abc_lib PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/to/external/lib/libabc.so
  IMPORTED_NO_SONAME TRUE
)
```

CMake will use */path/to/external/lib/libabc.so* instead of *-L/path/to/external/lib -llibabc.so* as link options if libabc.so has no soname in its ELF header.
You can verify this with:

```
readelf -d /path/to/external/lib/libabc.so
```

The offcial cmake doc:[Imported Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#id5) explains more details.